# How to do add the total of the input and how do I do an if-else statement within a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

1.How do I add the score when the user inputs the number. I don't understand. It keeps on printing out 4 instead of a higher score. Also, I need to return a boolean answer and when the 4 scores are more than 32 then the else if statement gets printed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class forloops
{
    public static void main (String[] param)
    {
        runnerscore();
        System.exit(0);

    }  //END main 

    public static void runnerscore()
    {
        int score = 1; // initialising the score that is kept throughout the program
        int input = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<=3; i++) // for loop for the questions
        {

            input(score, input); // 2nd method
            score = score + 1;
        }

        if (score<=32) // boolean expression and have used if-else statement
        {
            System.out.println("The team has " + score + " points so is legal"); // prints out what the score is and if it is legal
        }
        else if (score >32)
        {
            System.out.println("The team has " + score + " points so is NOT legal"); // prints out if the score is not legal
        }
    }

    public static int input(int score, int input) 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //enables scanner that lets the user input
        System.out.println("What is the disability class of runner " + score + "?");
        input = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());  
        return input;
    }
}//END DisabilityRate
```

Comment: What do you think `input(score, input);` does?

Comment: Prints out what is in the method input() using the for loop? and passes int score, int input as an argument to the 2nd method...

Comment: You're incrementing `score` exactly 4 times. Why do you think it would be more than 4?

Comment: I don't think I made the question clear enough, just very hard explaining on here what I mean. What I want to do is, add whatever the user inputs when the question 'System.out.println("What is the disability class of runner " + score + "?");' is asked. If the score is <=32 then it should print the if statement and if it is >32 then it prints out the else if statement.

Comment: Hm in plain English you want to run the for loop 4 times . And if the sum of 4 inputs >=32 enter first if or else enter the second if? The score will never be more than 4...

Comment: So I cannot add the 4 inputs together to be more than 32 because it will never be more than 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually store the `sum of inputs` also the score will maximize at 4 cause the for loop will run 4 times . Finally have a look at the code you may need:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Example {

    // Keep scanner reference here
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Example() {
        runnerScore();
    }

    /**
     * Main method
     * 
     * @param param
     */
    public static void main(String[] param) {
        new Example();
    }

    /**
     * A method
     */
    public void runnerScore() {

        int score = 1;
        int sumOfInputs = 0;

        // for loop for the questions
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

            int input = input(score); // You need to save somewhere the input
                                        // you get from the user....
            System.out.println("The (" + i + ") time , input from  user was " + input);

            sumOfInputs += input; // sum every input you get

            ++score; // which is like using score = score + 1 or score+=1
        }

        // boolean expression and have used if-else statement
        if (sumOfInputs <= 32) {

            // prints out what the score is and if it is legal
            System.out.println("\nThe team has " + sumOfInputs + " points so is legal");

        } else if (sumOfInputs > 32) {

            // prints out if the score is not legal
            System.out.println("\nThe team has " + sumOfInputs + " points so is NOT legal");

        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the input from the user
     * 
     * @param score
     * @return
     */
    public int input(int score) {
        int scannerInput = 0;

        System.out.println("\nWhat is the disability class of runner " + score + "?");

        // String -> integer
        scannerInput = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        // Return it
        return scannerInput;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand now and it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Bhavi Ready! Now it works ... Also asked this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40921049/java-scanner-nosuchelementexception-closing-system-in ) in case you are interested with an error it was happening when i modified your code)

Comment: Nice one! I was interested in knowing, didn't understand why it was happening